# Get (dbis, externalid )Element property using api in forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

we are working on to get element property from elementid and dbid, that we can get by loading model on viewer and access the method, but is there any api that forge provide, can we get element property without loading model for that is there any api is available or not.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get element parameters without opening the Forge Viewer, you can take advantage of the Model Derivative API itself. Here are three endpoints for your reference. Please execute them after your `svf/svf2` translation job is completed&successful, then run them by sequence.

1. https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-GET/
2. https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-GET/
3. https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/

Comment: is there any way to get elementid dbid map without loading model with the use of apis?
get that property of model by its map to dbid and i have stored elementid.

Comment: There is no elementid dbid map, but the viewer has externalId(Revit UniqueId) dbId map. However, unfortunately, there is no API supporting that w/o opening the model with Forge viewer at this moment.

Comment: Or you can consider run your own Revit adding on Design Automation API to export such data for your use.